# How further we can access a php get variable?

Tags: php

I have a page where i show the each person's brief record and there is link for details of each person which takes to another page if someone wants to edit record there is option on that page but making another get variable in not working.

```
<form action="std_edit.php?edit_id=<?php echo $std_id; ?>">
            <input class="std_edit" type="submit" name="edit" value = "Edit">
</form>
```

i echoed the previous get variable and its printing fine. how can i make it work fine for me?

Comment: How are you getting the variable edit_id in std_edit.php?

Comment: using $_GET['edit_id']

Comment: So.. you're telling us it's working fine but you can't have multiple get variables? Mind explaining that in a way we can understand?

Comment: I mean, I hope you do know that you just have to do `<form action="std_edit.php">` right? Every `<input/>` element with a name attribute after that will automaticly be passed along..

Comment: Try using a hidden input

Comment: @JhonFredyPedrozaPineda What are you talking about? The question has nothing to do with hidden inputs at all?!

Comment: yes but i want to edit only that particular id so by making get variable i can grab it and then edit it ...

Comment: I mean use `<input type=hidden" name="edit_id" value="<?php echo $std_id;?>">` to pass the parameter

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: problem is that the get variable i made in form tag is not working. it is getting appropriate value

Comment: As a @icecub says just put `<form action="std_edit.php">` and inside a hidden input like above

Answer (score 0):

First thing you can "GET" a variable as long as you can see that in the URL. e.g: exmaple.com?std_id=Boo

In code you do something:

```
$std_id = $_GET['std_id'];  //$std_id will be Boo
<form action="std_edit.php?edit_id=<?php echo $std_id; ?>">
            <input class="std_edit" type="submit" name="edit" value = "Edit">
</form>
```

If you want some variable it has to be there in URL.
Taking sample example above, you cannot do something like:

```
$std_id = $_GET['id'];
```

Reason, id is not there in URL.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that any GET variables set in your `action` attribute will be lost when you submit the form. This is because upon submit, the GET request is completely rebuild. All you have to do is:

```
<form action="std_edit.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="edit_id" value="<?php echo $std_id; ?>" />
    <input class="std_edit" type="submit" name="edit" value = "Edit" />
</form>
```

That will make it work again.

Comment: this thing worked but what if we want to update the records?

Comment: @KamranArshad What do you mean? If you want to update records, the `std_edit.php` page should take care of that. You just create a new form there where you insert all the existing data. Then, if the data is changed, just submit that form and update it in your database.